# Как проверить разрядность операционной системы?

Tags: ос, php

Как проверить разрядность операционной системы самого сервера с помощью php. Нужно узнать разрядность OS, прежде чем выполнить команду.

Answer (score 1):

Если это Линукс - вам нужен вывод команды arch. Если x86_64 - у вас 64-разрядная система.

Answer (score 1):

`php_uname('m')` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.php-uname.php

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите значение константы [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php): она будет в районе 2e9 для 32-битной, и 9e18 для 64-битной.

Comment: @Sergiks, это не гарантирует, что х32 не запущено на х64.